# Wht the php query return a single row

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i am developing a off-line chat application, i have two table 1. user details (cli_id,email, User name ) 2. chat table (c_from, c_to, subject, matter, image) now the problem is that i am taking the cli_id from the user table as from and to but when fetching the query it return a single row, my code looks like this

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="16%"><strong>From</strong></td>
    <td width="23%"><strong>Subject</strong></td>
    <td width="40%"><strong>Matter</strong></td>
    <td width="21%"><strong>To</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
    include('connect.php');
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `chat` ORDER BY chat_id DESC")or die(mysql_error());
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  {
   ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['c_from']; ?></td>
    <td><a href="read_chat.php?id=<?php echo $row['chat_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['subject']; ?></a></td>
    <td><a href="read_chat.php?id=<?php echo $row['chat_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['matter']; ?></a></td>
    <td><?php
$chat_to =$row['c_to'];
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE cli_id = $chat_to")or die(mysql_error());
  while($qry=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  {
  echo $qry['email'];
  }
   ?></td>
  </tr>

  <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Using the same variable names (e.g. $sql) for different query resultsets within nested loops is __not__ a good idea if you don't want values to be overwritten

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting `$sql` inside the loop, which replaces the result set in your outer loop with a result set which is already "emptied" by the time the code execution returns to the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

$sql variable changed inside the while loop. Use a different variable here:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE cli_id = $chat_to")or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="16%"><strong>From</strong></td>
    <td width="23%"><strong>Subject</strong></td>
    <td width="40%"><strong>Matter</strong></td>
    <td width="21%"><strong>To</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
    include('connect.php');
    $selectChat=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `chat` ORDER BY chat_id DESC")or die(mysql_error());
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($selectChat))
  {
   ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['c_from']; ?></td>
    <td><a href="read_chat.php?id=<?php echo $row['chat_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['subject']; ?></a></td>
    <td><a href="read_chat.php?id=<?php echo $row['chat_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['matter']; ?></a></td>
    <td><?php
$chat_to =$row['c_to'];
    $selectClient=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE cli_id = $chat_to")or die(mysql_error());
  while($qry=mysql_fetch_array($selectClient))
  {
  echo $qry['email'];
  }
   ?></td>
  </tr>

  <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better for you to use a join in order to minimize the amount of database requests, this will also reduce the need for you to have a second query loop inside the first loop. Try the following code

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
<td width="16%"><strong>From</strong></td>
<td width="23%"><strong>Subject</strong></td>
<td width="40%"><strong>Matter</strong></td>
<td width="21%"><strong>To</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php
include('connect.php');
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `chat` LEFT JOIN 'client' on 'chat.c_to = client.cli_id' ORDER BY chat_id DESC")or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['c_from']; ?></td>
<td><a href="read_chat.php?id=<?php echo $row['chat_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['subject']; ?></a>  </td>
<td><a href="read_chat.php?id=<?php echo $row['chat_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['matter']; ?></a></td>
<td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

You must need to rewrite the while statement that appears immediately after the main query

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
```

as

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($sql))
```

Hope this might help you.

Comment: Unlikely to help, and will actually trigger more errors in the code as the row values are being accessed by column name, not by numeric index